# Multiple File upload user control in AJAX ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have to create a multiple file upload user control with Ajax controls. 
The host page/master page will contain only the script manager control.

How am i going to achieve this as i am new to Ajax?
Will the entire user control built using Ajax controls or only the hosting container will be derived from Ajax kit like “Update Panel” or both can be done??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)?

Comment: Uploadify works well and customizable to file types.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best control is "Plupload".
I used it in several my applications.
http://www.plupload.com/

It works with several methods, like Gears, Browser+, HTML 5, Flash, Html 4 (it created unvisible) iframe for this.

So it works in any cases.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am restricted to use any third party dlls.have to purely rely on asp.net and Ajax implementations.